# Error: no operator "[]" matches these operands

Tags: c++

VS2017 is giving me the error:

[image: 1]

It is related to `const` keyword. But my class method do not change object variables, so it is constant. `m_points` and `m_pointsIndex` are

```
std::vector< std::shared_ptr < DB::Point > > m_points;
std::map<size_t, size_t> m_pointsIndex;
```

And method is

```
AcGePoint3d Database::getPoint(size_t index) const
{
    AcGePoint3d point;
    point.x = m_points[m_pointsIndex[index]]->x();
    point.y = m_points[m_pointsIndex[index]]->y();
    point.z = m_points[m_pointsIndex[index]]->z();

    return point;
}
```

All my data are stored in SQLite database. All objects reference each other using ID as FOREIGN KEY.
In the application I store all my points in `std::vector` for easy looping. And bind ID from SQLite to vector index with `std::map`.

In `getPoint(size_t index)` method, index are point ID in SQLite database. I convert database id to vector index with `m_pointsIndex[index]` and find point in `m_points` using it. From point I get x, y and z coordinates and create new point to return. So I don't modify any member variables. So why method can't be constant?

Comment: Look at the second answer, you are not using a `const` accessor.